# apache 2 does not install ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04

I am install apache2 ubuntu 16.04 .i am getting this error.

Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.

● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)

Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d

```
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
```

Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-06-30 15:19:36 IST; 10ms ago

```
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

Process: 18460 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=2)

Jun 30 15:19:36 shradha-Vostro-3546 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web se....

Jun 30 15:19:36 shradha-Vostro-3546 apache2[18460]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 46: ...

Jun 30 15:19:36 shradha-Vostro-3546 apache2[18460]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 57: ...
Jun 30 15:19:36 shradha-Vostro-3546 apache2[18460]: ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE ne...

Jun 30 15:19:36 shradha-Vostro-3546 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control pro...2

Jun 30 15:19:36 shradha-Vostro-3546 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2....

Jun 30 15:19:36 shradha-Vostro-3546 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entere....

Jun 30 15:19:36 shradha-Vostro-3546 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with....

please help me

Comment: Did you even try to read the message you get? Look at this line: "Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full."

Comment: Try running a systemctl status apache2 or journalctl -xe -l and paste the full output. I am mostly interested in the line with APACHE_PID_FILE. Please also check your apache2.conf file to be sure that's correct and cointains no errors

Comment: I'd debug it w/ apachectl instead of this nonsense.

Comment: This is not a nonsense question.If you have any suggestion so you can help us, otherwise don't waste your time to write comment.